# How put the correct "url" for a getConnection with DriverManager?

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database in an Android application but am unable to do so.

The URL I'm using for the connection to a MySQL database is: `jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.x.xxx/dbname`, where xx.xx.x.xxx represents the IP address of my server. The database `dbname` is managed by phpMyAdmin on this server.

But I always receive the same error : `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

I have the internet PERMISSION in my manifest.

The code I'm using:

```
private void callSQL() {
    java.sql.Connection laConnection;
    java.sql.Statement transmission;
    ResultSet leResultat;

    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            laConnection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.x.xxx/dbname", "user", "passwrd");

            transmission = laConnection.createStatement();
            leResultat= transmission.executeQuery("select * from Communes");

            while (leResultat.next()) {
                System.out.println("Commune : "+ leResultat.getString("Nom"));
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I have been able to use another solution with a HTTP request on a PHP page that connects to the database. This solution works well, but which one is the best way to use?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem wasn't the code. The problem is the connection. I hadn't the permission to connect the database. With the permission allowed to a distant user on the database, it was OK.